# I need to create a department wide SharePoint Calendar that retrieves information from their personal O365 calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

If someone enters they need the 20th of February off in their personal calender I need that to populate into a group SharePoint calendar.  Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can add your group shared calendar email address as attendee when you add an event in your private calendar. Then this event will appear both in your personal calendar and group calendar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of good solutions out there to help you overlay and display personal calendars. You should check out the VirtoSoftware Calendar App, it's powerful but pretty easy to use. You can create new calendars and then overlay as many personal or shared calendars as you would like.

http://go.virtosoftware.com/office-365-calendar-app

Bamboo along with some custom SharePoint component providers have some solutions as well. Just depends on your specific needs and budget!